# How to gather the first coordinates and merge all coordinates of a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `all_a` whose each element is a list of length 2. I would like to gather the first coordinates and merge all coordinates. I do it with a loop which seems not efficient with big `all_a`.

Could you please elaborate on a more efficient/faster method?

```
a1 = ['a', ['link1', 'link2']]
a2 = ['b', ['link3']]
a3 = ['c', ['link4', 'link5', 'link6']]
a4 = ['d', []]

all_a = [a1, a2, a3, a4]
first = []
second = []

for a in all_a:
    first.append(a[0])
    second += a[1]
```

The expected result is `first = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and `second = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4', 'link5', 'link6']`.

Comment: Please explain what you expect as "efficient".  Your current solution is a simple linear loop (although with a higher cost on the merge).  It seems easy enough to follow.

Comment: @Prune I hope for a faster method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a1 = ['a', ['link1', 'link2']]
a2 = ['b', ['link3']]
a3 = ['c', ['link4', 'link5', 'link6']]
a4 = ['d', []]

all_a = [a1, a2, a3, a4]
```

Perhaps this is more what you want.  Converting the lists to sets is a liner operation, reducing the complexity of the result.

Make a list of the first elements.
Make the set union of the second elements, turning the final result back to a list.

```
first = [item[0] for item in a]
second = set()
for item in all_a:
    second = second.union(set(item[1]))
```

The `second` processing *can* be converted to a single-line `map` application, but it's harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Given Data:

```
a1 = ['a', ['link1', 'link2']]
a2 = ['b', ['link3']]
a3 = ['c', ['link4', 'link5', 'link6']]
a4 = ['d', []]
```

Your solution seems efficient enough but this might be what you are looking for:
For the first set, you can do:

```
first = [a[0] for a in all_a]
```

For the second, this will create a list of lists.

```
second = [a[1] for a in all_a if len(a[1]) > 0] #this will create a list of lists
second = [item for sublist in second for item in sublist] #this will create a list of lists and will do the required job.
```

Edit: Also a replacement for the doing it in 2 lines, you can simply write:

```
second = [item for sublist in (a[1] for a in all_a) for item in sublist]
```

This will produce the expected output as:

**first**: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], **second**: ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4', 'link5', 'link6']